# Как работать с куками в расширении Chrome?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, расширения

Всем привет, помогите с проблемой:
Пользователь качает и устанавливает расширение для браузера Chrome. Это расширение работает с веб-запросами, имитирует пользовательскую активность на нескольких сайтах через IP пользователя.

Проблема в том, что при работе с куками они хранятся в браузере. Если пользователь зайдет на сайт через этот же браузер, то там будут те куки с которыми работало расширение (а некоторые сайты в куках передают сессии и от них много что зависит)

Пример: Я зашел на сайт test.com, авторизовался на нем, и в куках он мне передал сессию. Установил расширение для браузера которое автоматизирует работу на этом сайте но с другого аккаунта, расширение начинает работать, соответственно авторизуется на сайте test.com под другим аккаунтом, а это автоматом завершает предыдущую сессию в этом браузере, а нужно чтоб пользователь этого не замечал.

Если выше ничего не понятно, что вероятней всего, попробую более понятнее спросить.
Как сделать так, чтоб расширение браузера Chrome в фоновом режиме создавала "Инкогнито режим" браузера и в нем работало, но чтоб никакого нового окна браузера не всплывало.
Либо **как реализовать работу с куками в расширении так, чтоб куки не мешали работе пользователя в браузере?**